# What is the difference between EF POCO and EF Code First?

Tags: ef-code-first, poco

What is the difference between EF POCO and EF Code First?

If I am starting with just POCOs can I use EF with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use EF code first you have POCO objects and the database is created with code from the DbContext class. You get no visual designer when using code first.

You can also use POCOs for “ordinary” EF but then your database will be handled by an edmx file and a visual designer.

Wich approach you use is up to you as a developer, but my opinion is that the code first alternative is cleaner than the edmx solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just a supplement: you can use Code First in case your database exist first too. In this case you are using POCO classes too and you are describing all the relationships via Fluent API or Data Annotation. This approach is called Reverse Engineering.

Generally, POCO is some simple object, exactly "Plain Old CLR Object" and Code First is the approach that is working with the POCOs.